# Problems with Cisco Aironet 1200 FastEthernet connection

Tags: cisco

I'm trying to connect to my router by using the FastEthernet0.

I did the following commands:

```
conf t
int f0
ip addr 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
no shut
```

And i got the following configuration:

```
ap#sh ip interface brief
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
BVI1                       unassigned      YES DHCP   up                    up
Dot11Radio0                unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
Dot11Radio1                unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
FastEthernet0              10.0.0.1        YES manual up                    up
```

I also created a manual lan connection on Windows with:

```
IP: 10.0.0.10
Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 10.0.0.1
```

But i can't connect to my router :\

Comment: Are you trying to telnet, or what do you mean by can't connect?

Comment: @RonMaupin I can't establish a lan connection. But i also can't ping 10.0.0.1

Comment: If FA0/0 is up, it has a connection. Is your Windows ehternet connection showing up?

Comment: @RonMaupin Yeah, but it says "Unidentified network or Limited or no connectivity"

Comment: That's fine since you probably have not identified the network, and you are using the ethernet connection that would normally go to the router from the access point so there is no Internet connectivity that Windows can find. The AP may purposely not respond to pings. If you set up the passwords, can you telnet or http/https to it?

Comment: Just configured the AP and i can't telnet it.

Comment: By the way, you call this a router in your question, but it is not a router, it is a wireless access point that should connect to a router on the ethernet port. You would then connect through the WAP to the network. You seem to be totally lost, and you may want to ask this on chat since this area is not for extended discussions like this.

Comment: This is a link to the manual (PDF) for this device: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCwQFjACahUKEwi5_7mXjJPIAhXKCJIKHWG6BGE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cisco.com%2Fc%2Fdam%2Fen%2Fus%2Ftd%2Fdocs%2Fwireless%2Faccess_point%2F1200%2Fvxworks%2Finstallation%2Fguide%2F1200hig2.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHvjm-4alg3QMicjK6Hmhpdx-7Vtw&sig2=BPlbzOBk9xEZSh-mvn_Npg&cad=rja

Comment: Are you plugged directly into the access point, or are you connected via a switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address goes on BVI1, not fa0. It's a bridge, not router.

I don't know why Cisco even allows you to enter such a configuration. You cannot unbridge the interfaces either; you can enter the commands, it just won't work.

Comment: That's correct. Packetlife (http://packetlife.net/blog/2012/feb/20/aironet-aps-bridge-groups-and-bvi/) has an excellent explanation of all the interfaces in an aironet access point, and how the all tie together: BVI is for management and you can create subinterfaces on Fa0 to bridge various VLANs to different SSIDs. BVI must be in bridge group 1.